# Using Where clause in Multiple relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Apparently it seems like the following WHERE clause will not work because we have two relationships (WorksAt and ResponsibleFor) in our query. If there was only one relationship  then this would work like magic. Here in the query below the query returns all the courses in teh department science but it does not filter out courses NOT taught by Maria Smith. All i want to do is get only the courses taught by Maria Smith who works in Science Department.
 I came across WITH and Start Clause that seem to be potential candidate clauses  make it work where you could filter out one part of the query before sending it to another.

 http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html 

but i havent been able to grasp the concept yet. Anyone up for help?

```
MATCH (d:Department)<-[w:WorksAt]-(t:Tutor)-[r:ResponsibleFor]->(c:Courses) 
WHERE d.name='Science' 
AND  t.name='Maria Smith'
return  c,r
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. Try return * instead of c,r

Comment: Barring that, are you sure all of your cases match for labels, properties and relationship types?

Comment: @DaveBennett  The return * will bring the same result as return c,r. Also the labels,properties and relationship types are matched on cases as i am aware Neo4j Cypher query is case sensitive not only with query syntax but with the values we put in as well

Comment: Sorry, misread on my part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to skin this particular cat. Let's break it down.

Find the tutor whose name is 'Maria Smith' that works in the 'Science' department

```
MATCH (d:Department)<-[:WorksAt]-(t:Tutor)
WHERE d.name = 'Science' AND t.name = 'Maria Smith'
RETURN t
```

Find the courses that a tutor teaches

```
MATCH (t:Tutor)-[:ResponsibleFor]->(c:Courses)
RETURN t.name, c
```

Bring these two together to get the courses that Maria Smith from the Scence department teaches

```
MATCH (d:Department)<-[:WorksAt]-(t:Tutor)
WHERE d.name = 'Science' AND t.name = 'Maria Smith'
WITH t
MATCH (t)-[r:ResponsibleFor]->(c:Courses)
RETURN t.name, r, c
```

This can also be written as

```
MATCH (d:Department { name : 'Science' })<-[:WorksAt]-(t:Tutor { name : 'Maria Smith' })
WITH t
MATCH (t)-[r:ResponsibleFor]->(c:Courses)
RETURN t.name, r, c
```

To maximise query performance you can use schema indexes to quickly locate your Department and Tutor nodes. Are you doing this? To create the indexes use

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Department(name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Tutor(name)
```

Run these lines separately.

As an aside were you to want to list the courses that each tutor taught, as suggested above in the second query, you could use the following query to aggregate the courses for each tutor.

```
MATCH (t:Tutor)-[:ResponsibleFor]->(c:Courses)
RETURN t.name as CourseTutor, collect(c.name) as CourseName
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @ceej thank you for your answer. i'll let you know once i fully test it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice breakdown.  For performance details on this type of query, refer to Wes Freeman's [Pragmatic Cypher Optimization](http://wes.skeweredrook.com/pragmatic-cypher-optimization-2-0-m06/).  In setting up the match, start with the smaller node set and work toward the larger (Wes's Rule 4).